# 'jsi/jsi.h' file not found - Error when upgrading react-native from 0.64.0 to 0.71.12

Tags: react-native

This upgrade from `0.64.0` to `0.71.12` is by far the most painful I have had with RN.

I have solved 3 other issues until I stumbled on this one that I can't seem to solve. I haven't been able to compile it yet.

When trying to run the app on the iOS Simulator I get the following error:

```js
  'jsi/jsi.h' file not found
```

The only related issue I found was [this one](https://github.com/Nozbe/WatermelonDB/issues/691), which is associated with a third-party lib.
From the stack trace, I feel this might be coming from react-native itself.

**Any help or hint is very welcome!**

[image]

[image: error screenshot]

Comment: I'm seeing the same exact issue. Hoping someone contributes an answer.

Comment: @JayKoutavas I looked everywhere and tried tons of things but nothing works. Currently starting a new project from scratch. Very painful.

Answer (score 0):

I checked file `react-native/packages/react-native/ReactCommon/jsi/React-jsi.podspec` and I found these lines:

```
  if js_engine == :jsc
    s.source_files  = "**/*.{cpp,h}"
    s.exclude_files = [
                        "jsi/jsilib-posix.cpp",
                        "jsi/jsilib-windows.cpp",
                        "**/test/*"
                      ]

  elsif js_engine == :hermes
    # JSI is provided by hermes-engine when Hermes is enabled
    # Just need to provide JSIDynamic in this case.
    s.source_files = "jsi/JSIDynamic.{cpp,h}"
    s.dependency "hermes-engine"
  end
end
```

The file `jsi.h` was not found because `js_engine` was set to `:hermes`.

I switched it to `:jsc` and it helped.

Here is how to do it in Podfile:

1. Change ios version to at least 13:

```
platform :ios, '13.0'
```

2. Disable hermes when calling `use_react_native`:

```
  use_react_native!(
    :path => "../node_modules/react-native",
    :hermes_enabled => false,
    # ...
```

That helped me.